# How to define a formula based on user's input from keyboard? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

It's my very first question so I hope I'll put it right.

I'm doing some predefined exercises in Python and one request is to define the following formula:

**{6*[2+(a-1)%b]*2a}**    with user's input from the keyboard.

If I am to pick the "a" and "b" my self, the formula is working, however, when ask input from user (`raw_input`) I'm getting an error and I can't figure out why.

The code I tried looks like this:

```
a = raw_input("enter the first number")
b = raw_input("enter the second number")

print (6*(2+(a-1)%b)*2**a)
```

And the error message is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Victor

Answer (score 1):

In python2, which you sadly chose to use, the function `raw_input` returns a string. You must convert it into a number:

```
a = float(raw_input("enter the first number"))
b = float(raw_input("enter the second number"))
```

And `2**a` probably should be `2*a`, unless you raise 2 to power `a`.